# Session bean timeout issues

Tags: jsf, expired-sessions

So because all my jsf managed beans are session scoped, whenever the session expires due to idleness(e.g. user leaving his screen unattended) then, it gives an exception. What is a good jsf/jee based solution for this?( no jsp or servlets please)
edit:I dont want the exceptions to show to the user, and maybe have some sort of redirect to the login page or "your session has expired" message..whatever is feasible.

Comment: solution to what? Your beans work as expected.

Comment: I dont want the exceptions to show to the user, and maybe have some sort of redirect to the login page or "your session has expired" message..whatever is feasible.